# "The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value" when creating WebApp resource from Node.js

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create a simple WebApp using the Azure SDK for JS in a Node.js environment, but I keep getting the response:

```
{
  "Code":"BadRequest",
  "Message":"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.",
  "Target":null,
  "Details":[
    {"Message":"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."},
    {"Code":"BadRequest"},
    {"ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode":"01007",
        "MessageTemplate":"The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
        "Parameters":["LinuxFxVersion"],
        "Code":"BadRequest",
        "Message":"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."}
    }],
  "Innererror":null
}
```

I've tried a variety of different sets of properties and environments with no success. I always get this error. Here's a snippet of the TypeScript code I am using:

```
    const wsmClient: WebSiteManagementClient...
    const webAppName: string...
    const servicePlanId: string...
    const rgName: string...
    const envelope: Site = {
      name: webAppName,
      location: 'westus2',
      kind: 'app,linux',
      serverFarmId: servicePlanId,
      siteConfig: {
        linuxFxVersion: 'JAVA|11-java11'
      }
    };
    const appResp = await wsmClient.webApps.createOrUpdate(
      rgName,
      webAppName,
      envelope
    );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 40):

**Reason**:

Your app service plan is not Linux, actually it's Windows. Windows host doesn't have parameter LinuxFxVersion.

If we create a site without explicitly configuring the host as Linux, it will be a Windows host/serverFarm/app service plan by default. Using {"kind":"linux"} is not enough.

**Solution**:

Explicitly define the app service plan in Linux, and make sure `{"reserved": true}` to set it as a Linux host ([See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#appserviceplanproperties))

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "kind": "app,linux",
    "properties": {
        "reserved": true
    },
    "sku": {
        "Tier": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuTier')]",
        "Name": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuName')]"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I test your json data, it's caused your `properties`. Your json data has no "properties" property. If you want to create web with the json property check this web app Rest API request body：[Web Apps - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate#request-body).

The correct format should be like the below sample:

```
  {
    "location": "CentralUS",
    "kind":"app,linux",
    "properties":{
          "serverFarmId":"your Resource ID",
        "siteConfig":{
            "linuxFxVersion":"JAVA|11-java11"
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks George. You are right about needing properties, but the Azure SDK for JS has these model mappers that map JS objects (like `envelope` in my snippet above) to the actual request body, so the `serverFarmId` in my code will actually be mapped to `properties.serverFarmId` in the REST API request body. I've found a workaround using a template deployment, but I am still curious about the problem I'm having with the SDK for JS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue while deploying the webapp using Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app_service" {
  name                = "app-name"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.plan.id
     
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      docker_image     = "<image-registry>"
      docker_image_tag = var.GIT_VERSION
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, docker_image_tag version was not populated correctly. After providing the correct value, Terraform deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

@imwenyz answer helped me.

I am running as Azure DevOps pipeline, which has AzureWebApp@1 task. And the app service on Azure that I configured is windows based.

I am getting the error at this task as follows.

```
##[error]Error: Failed to patch App Service 'BasicReactApp' configuration. Error: BadRequest - The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value. (CODE: 400)
```

So I had to modify the task as follows.

```
      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: '
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
          #appType: webAppLinux # this is the cause for the error in my case.
          appType: webApp
          appName: $(webAppName)
          runtimeStack: 'NODE|14.x'
          package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          startUpCommand: 'npm run start'
```

Basically, as you can see, changed the appType from **webAppLinux** to **webApp**