# Pulumi azure-native provider: Azure WebApp: The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-app-service-plans, pulumi

I created a new Pulumi Typescript program using the Pulumi CLI with `pulumi new azure-typescript` and created the following `index.ts` (based on the new [azure-native provider](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native)):

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as azure from "@pulumi/azure-native";

const resourceGroup = new azure.resources.ResourceGroup("rg-spring-boot", {location: "West Europe"});

const appServicePlan = new azure.web.AppServicePlan("sp-spring-boot", {
    location: resourceGroup.location,
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    kind: "Linux",
    sku: {
        name: "B1",
        tier: "Basic",
    },
});

// Image https://hub.docker.com/r/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs
const imageName = "jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs:latest";

const appServiceSpringBoot = new azure.web.WebApp("spring-boot-vuejs-azure", {
    location: resourceGroup.location,
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id,
    siteConfig: {
        linuxFxVersion: `DOCKER|${imageName}`,
    },
    httpsOnly: true,
});
```

Now running a `pulumi up -y` I get the following error:

```
pulumi up -y
Previewing update (dev)

View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-pulumi-azure/dev/previews/3317933e-0051-4dfc-b436-8fe4184d11f5

     Type                        Name                          Plan
     pulumi:pulumi:Stack         spring-boot-pulumi-azure-dev
 +   └─ azure-native:web:WebApp  spring-boot-vuejs-azure       create

Outputs:
  + helloEndpoint: output<string>

Resources:
    + 1 to create
    3 unchanged

Updating (dev)

View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-pulumi-azure/dev/updates/5

     Type                        Name                          Status                  Info
     pulumi:pulumi:Stack         spring-boot-pulumi-azure-dev  **failed**              1 error
 +   └─ azure-native:web:WebApp  spring-boot-vuejs-azure       **creating failed**     1 error

Diagnostics:
  azure-native:web:WebApp (spring-boot-vuejs-azure):
    error: Code="BadRequest" Message="The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value." Details=[{"Message":"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","ExtendedCode":"01007","Message":"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.","MessageTemplate":"The parameter {0} has an invalid value.","Parameters":["LinuxFxVersion"]}}]

  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (spring-boot-pulumi-azure-dev):
    error: update failed

Resources:
    3 unchanged

Duration: 22s
```

Here's also [the full example project](https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-pulumi-aws-azure-google/tree/main/spring-boot-pulumi-azure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731474/4964553) the problem lies within the Azure AppService configuration in `azure.web.AppServicePlan`. Although we set the `kind: "Linux"`, it's actually a Windows machine.

The missing parameter is `reserved: true,` inside our AppService:

```
const appServicePlan = new azure.web.AppServicePlan("sp-spring-boot", {
    location: resourceGroup.location,
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    kind: "Linux",
    reserved: true,
    sku: {
        name: "B1",
        tier: "Basic",
    },
});
```

[As the documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-09-01/serverfarms?tabs=json#appserviceplanproperties-object) without setting `reserved` parameter to true we got a Windows machine. This even show up in the Azure Portal, if you use `kind: "Linux"` without the parameter:

[image]